# Paypal Return and Review

Tags: checkout, payment, payment-gateway, paypal, css

My client has recently moved server and Paypal is not returning the customers anymore to the site for review in the middle of the order and return ( to confirm a successful tx) like it used to. What are the factors which control this? What URL should we give to paypal so that the customer gets a this return at the end saying there was a successful transaction. A bit confused because if we give for instance the home page then the customer would not get the successful transaction message but there was no CMS page set up to achieve this either, so it must have been generated by paypal.

We are using Paypal standard.

Also there is the use SSL setting in the Paypal standard settings. Is this supposed to be yes or not. Client has an SSL cert.

Comment: What version are you currently running? Have you tried to reinput all the PayPal credentials? Sometimes (depending on how you transfer the database) the encoded values can get messed up. I am assuming it is running the same Magento CE version on the new server that it was running on the old server?

Answer (score 2):

You should set your site url in website preference in paypal account and ipn url of site in ipn url in your paypal profile.
And keep auto return on in paypal profile.